# BNF Parse Tree Inquiry

Tags: bnf

I am currently enrolled in a computer architecture class and I'm trying to do one of the homework assignments.

The assignment is on BNF and even after having the lecture, reading the slides, and looking online, I'm still stumped.

Here is my grammar:

```
<expr>-><expr> + <term> |
          <expr> - <term> |
          <term>
<term>-><term> * <factor> |
          <term> / <factor> |
          <factor>
<factor>->(<expr>)|<id>
<id>->A|B|C|D
```

**What would the parse tree look like for `A + (C - D) / B`?**

I just need a little guidance and I will be able to do this problem for myself. My teacher does not explain very well so I was hoping for explanation in laymans terms of how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Though it is not stated, I assume that we are trying to interpret the string **A + (C - D) / B** as an `<expr>` (as no other parse works).

`<expr>` is a nonterminal symbol, i.e. it does not occur literally the final string. Rather, the first rule (`<expr> -> <expr> + <term> | <expr> - <term> | <term>`) tells us what symbols to expect in a string that is an `<expr>`. It states that an `<expr>` can be made from one of the following options:

- `<expr> + <term>`, i.e. an `<expr>` followed by `+` followed by a `<term>`, or
- `<expr> - <term>`, (interpreted similarly), or
- `<term>`

Without getting into the details of how a parser would mechanically make the decision, we have to choose one of these options to proceed building a parse tree. I will choose the first option (`<expr> + <term>`), which assumes that the first `<expr>` will represent the **A** in the message, the `+` is literally the **+**, and the `<term>` is the remaining **(C - D) / B**. Thus the beginning of our parse tree looks like:

```
     <expr>
     / | \
    /  |  \
<expr> + <term>
```

This is not yet a complete parse, as it is not immediately clear from the rules that an `<expr>` can give the result **A**. Likewise **(C - D) / B** is not an immediate option for `<term>`. We can answer the first objection by seeing that:

1. `<expr>` can be `<term>` (by the third option of the rule for `<expr>`)
2. `<term>` in turn can be `<factor>` (by the third option of the rule for `<term>`)
3. `<factor>` can be `<id>` (by the second option of the rule for `<factor>`), and finally
4. `<id>` can be **A** (by the first option of the rule for `<id>`)

This line of reasoning fills in the parse tree as follows:

```
      <expr>
      / | \
     /  |  \
 <expr> | <term>
   |    |
 <term> |
   |    |
<factor>|
   |    |
  <id>  |
   |    |
   A    +
```

I hope that this gives you an idea of the process and the meaning of the rules, so that you can show further how `<term>` can give **(C - D) / B** and thus fill in the rest of the tree.

Comment: Yes, you are correct in thinking that the input goes in for `<expr>`. I think I managed to figure it out. Here is an image of my parse tree: http://i.imgur.com/GVArYJw.png

Comment: I think a few levels of your tree are backwards (the nonterminals should appear in the same left-to-right order as they occur in the rules), but your structure looks correct.